# ElectronJS : UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ReferenceError: fetch is not defined

Tags: javascript, electron, electron-builder

I am trying to build @loaders.gl(https://github.com/visgl/loaders.gl). I am adding to electron.js project. But when i build I am getting error

```
ReferenceError: fetch is not defined
    @loaders.gl/core/dist/es5/lib/fetch/fetch-file.js:42:13)


const { I3SConverter } = require("@loaders.gl/tile-converter");

module.exports = {
  convertFiles: async (url, outputPath) => {
    const converter = new I3SConverter();
    const tilesetJson = await converter.convert({
      inputUrl: url,
      outputPath: "data",
      inputType: "3DTILES",
      slpk: true,
      egmFilePath: "http://127.0.0.1:8081/deps/egm2008-5.pgm",
      tilesetName: "BatchedColors",
      token:
        "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJqdGkiOiJlYWMxMzcyYy0zZjJkLTQwODctODNlNi01MDRkZmMzMjIxOWIiLCJpZCI6OTYyMCwic2NvcGVzIjpbImFzbCIsImFzciIsImdjIl0sImlhdCI6MTU2Mjg2NjI3M30.1FNiClUyk00YH_nWfSGpiQAjR5V2OvREDq1PJ5QMjWQ",
    });
  },
};
```

**How i call it**

```
      let inputFile = "http://127.0.0.1:8081/tileset.json";
  convertFiles(inputFile, "");
```

I add added node-fetch but its not working. do anyone have idea

```
https://loaders.gl/modules/tile-converter/docs/cli-reference/tile-converter
https://github.com/visgl/loaders.gl/tree/master/modules/tile-converter
```

Thanks

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Hi I had updated code please check